# Nightmare Class - floats/strings

Tags: java, class

This is my class reponsible for new item entries, and from the start it has been a complete nightmare, I can't seem to resolve the issues I am facing which are:

setStock(float) in Item cannot be applied to ()

Item entry:

```
private void writeItemRecord()
         {
             // Check to see if we can connect to database table
             if ( DataBaseHandler.makeConnectionToitemDB() == -1)
               {
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (frame, "Unable to connect to database table (Item)");
               }
             else  // Ok, so first read data from the text fields
               {
                   // Read data from form and store data     

                   String Itemname = ItemnameTxtField.getText();
                   String Itemcode = ItemcodeTxtField.getText();
                   String Description = DescriptionTxtField.getText();
                   String Unitprice = UnitpriceTxtField.getText();
                   String Style = StyleTxtField.getText();
                   String Finish = FinishTxtField.getText();
                   String Stock = StockTxtField.getText();



                   // Convert priceStr to a float
                   Float fvar = Float.valueOf(Unitprice);
                   float price = fvar.floatValue();

                   Float svar = Float.valueOf(Stock);
                   float stock = svar.floatValue();

                   // Create a Item oject
                   Item Item = new Item();

                   // Set the attributes for the Item object

                   Item.setItemname (Itemname);
                   Item.setItemcode (Itemcode);
                   Item.setDescription (Description);
                   Item.setUnitprice (price);
                   Item.setStock(stock);
                   Item.setStyle(Style);
                   Item.setFinish(Finish);

                   // Write Item record.  Method writeToItemTable() returns
                   // 0 of OK writing record, -1 if there is a problem.  I store
                   // the returned value in a variable called error.
                   int error = DataBaseHandler.writeToItemTable(Item.getItemname(),
                                                                Item.getItemcode(),
                                                                Item.getDescription(),
                                                                Item.getUnitprice(), 
                                                                Item.setStock(),
                                                                Item.setStyle(Style),
                                                                Item.setFinish(Finish),
                                                                Item.setSuppliercode(Suppliercode),
                                                                Item.setSuppliername(Suppliername),
                                                                Item.setAddress(Address)
                                                                );

                   // Check if there is a problem writing the record, in 
                   // which case error will contain -1                                         
                   if (error == -1)
                     {
                         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (frame, "Problem writing record to Item Table");
                     }

                  // Clear the form - actual method is coded below
                  clearForm();

                  // Close database connection.  Report an error message
                  // if there is a problem.
                  if ( DataBaseHandler.closeConnection() == -1 )
                     {
                         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (frame, "Problem closing data   base conection");
                     }
                }

         }  // End
```

Any help is much appreciated!

And item extracts:

```
public void setStock(float StockIn)
  {
      Stock = StockIn;
  }   

public float getStock()
  {
     return Stock;
  }
```

Comment: Strange code. The line `Item Item = new Item();` confuses me. It should be `Item item = new Item();` (with lowercase "i"). Same in the `Item` class. Don't use capital first letters for your variables.

Comment: I have made the capital letter changes now, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

For starters, adhere to Java naming conventions. Nothing except class/interface names is allowed to use CamelCase. Use lowerCamelCase. As for your "problem", you wrote

```
Item.setStock(),
```

so obviously it's giving you the error. It is also giving you the exact line number of the error, something that would obviously have helped us to diagnose your problem.

Solution: use Item.getStock() (i suppose, it's hard to tell). Calling Item.setStock at that position (as an argument to a method call) is meaningless anyway, given that setStock is a void method.

Comment: +1 for naming conventions. Especially looking at float stock vs String Stock vs float Stock. You should also note that `Item Item = new Item()` is going to cause trouble.

Comment: @thagorn Is it? I was about to fire up Eclipse to see what that monstrosity really did to Java :)

Comment: Actually thats a good question. I don't know if you are going to overwrite the local name of the Item class with the Item variable (I know some languages do this) or if you are just going to be calling the Item class instead of the Item variable in every instance after this. Either way, undesired behavior and bad practice.

Comment: @thagorn Tried it: `String String = "String"; System.out.println(String);` compiles and runs normally, however it may sting our eyes :) So I would leave the general advice to never, ever use CamelCase for anything that isn't a reference type :)

Comment: Can you use String as a class successfully afterwards? (That would be impressively robust) And what happens if you call String.method() where it is ambiguous if you mean the class or the variable?

Comment: `String String = "String"; System.out.println(String.toUpperCase() + String.valueOf(3));` still works, but just barely. You can access a static method through a reference. Surprisingly, this still works as the next line: `String String2 = "String2"; System.out.println(String2.toUpperCase());` So it's robust.

Answer (score 3):

Java compiler errors come with a line number - pay attention to it. This is your problem:

```
Item.setStock()
```

`setStock()` requires a parameter, you are trying to call it without one. Perhaps you meant `getStock()`? And I suspect that all the calls to set methods in the parameter list to `writeToItemTable` are also wrong, as those set methods will have `void` as return value, so you can't use them that way.

Comment: How would I fix those set methods?

Comment: @writeToItemTable: there's nothing wrong with them, what's wrong is how they're used. First of all, you're using some variables that are not defined anywhere (Suppliercode, Suppliername, Address), the the writeToItemTable should have one parameter, the Item object, rather than extracting its fields just after setting them.

Comment: I understand, Thanks for that. I've now set up the code, name and address. I no longer receive the same error message. instead I get a REALLY long one about the database handler.

Comment: @silverj2k7: it probably says that the number and/or type the writeToItemTable is defined with does not match what you're trying to call it with. As I said: change it to take only one parameter, the Item object.

Answer (score 1):

The `setStock` method looks like this:

```
public void setStock(float StockIn)
```

To call it, you need to pass a float as an argument. Somewhere in your code, you call the method, like this:

```
Item.setStock(),
```

The method needs to be called with the float argument, but instead it's called with none, hence you see a compilation error.

Comment: So it should be:
Item.setStock(float StockIn) ?

Comment: No, you're calling the wrong method, you mean to call `Item.getStock()`. I also suggest you re-read how declaring and calling methods works in Java.

Comment: I think i just need sleep, spent the last 8 and a half hours doing this =/

Comment: Before you get back on the problem after your break, be sure to read all the comments and answers on this page, there's a lot of helpful tips from everyone.

Comment: Yes, I just took a quick breather and now I completely understood what I was doing wrong. I still have an error but I am pasted the error, I went back and took away the capital letters from my variables.

This is the new error:item.setItemname (itemname);

Comment: item.setItemname (itemname);

Cannot find symbol - method setItemname(java.lang.string) maybe you meant: getItemname or setItemname(String)

Answer (score 1):

In this code:

```
int error = DataBaseHandler.writeToItemTable(Item.getItemname(),
                                             Item.getItemcode(),
                                             Item.getDescription(),
                                             Item.getUnitprice(), 
                     // Right here -->       Item.setStock(),
                                             Item.setStyle(Style),
                                             Item.setFinish(Finish),
                                             Item.setSuppliercode(Suppliercode),
                                             Item.setSuppliername(Suppliername),
                                             Item.setAddress(Address)
                                             );
```

Notice that you're calling `Item.setStock()`, `Item.setStyle(Style)`, etc. instead of `Item.getStock()`, `Item.getStyle()`, etc.  This is probably the source of your problem - you're trying to call the `setStock()` method with no arguments, hence the error.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
// Create a Item oject
               Item Item = new Item();
```

Is problematic.  Not only is it bad style in Java to use uppercase names for variables, this particular instance results in a compile error.  Also, you're calling `setStock` without a parameter.  You need to fix that as well.

Comment: I apologise, I am a complete novice

Answer (score 1):

Here is your error:

```java
int error = DataBaseHandler.writeToItemTable(Item.getItemname(),
    Item.getItemcode(),
    Item.getDescription(),
    Item.getUnitprice(), 
    Item.setStock(), // <<< here! should be getStock()
    Item.setStyle(Style),
    Item.setFinish(Finish),
    Item.setSuppliercode(Suppliercode),
    Item.setSuppliername(Suppliername),
    Item.setAddress(Address));
```

But again... consider naming/coding conventions.

Comment: I have changed all of the .set to .get and I still get the error!